# Initialize a Class, if it it has in its constructor an Interface as a Parameter?

Tags: java, constructor, interface, superclass, super

There is a Class called TrianglePictureFilter, which has a the following constructor:

```
public TrianglePictureFilter(IPointGenerator pointGenerator) {
        super(pointGenerator);
    }
```

IPointGenerator is an interface:

```
import java.awt.Point;

/**
 * Point generator interface, providing points for generating geometric primitives.
 */
public interface IPointGenerator {
    /**
     * Generates the next (random) point.
     * 
     * @return a new point
     */
    public Point nextPoint();
}
```

I would like to use one of the methods of TrianglePictureFilter in another class, I have imported it, but I do not know how to initialize it, or to be more precise how to initialize the parameter in the constructor. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: TrianglePictureFilter should get pointGenerator that was already initialized before. It is just a simple use of polymorphism - hold instance with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have not already implemented your `IPointGenerator` class, you would do it like this:

```
public class TrianglePictureFilter implements IPointGenerator {

    public Point nextPoint() {
        // Return your random point.
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this exactly what you were asking for, but to use this code, it would be as simple as this:

```
TrianglePictureFilter filter = new TrianglePictureFilter();
Point randomPoint = filter.nextPoint();
```

Is this the kind of behavior you were looking for? If not, you probably don't want to use an `interface`.

Answer (score 0):

An object must inherit the IPointGenerator interface like so:

class AClass: IPointerGenerator
{

```
 public Point nextPoint()
 {
       //do some action here to return a point

 }
```

}

//Once that is done

AClass = new AClass();
// which can be passed into that constructor. This should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous class declaration when you instantiate the class.                 new TrianglePictureFilter(new IPointGenerator { public Point newPoint{  // do something }});